# Save same image pair over epochs with tf.summary.image for semantic segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

When training a deep network for semantic segmentation we can get a qualitative understanding of network performance by looking at the triad of image/ground truth/prediction.  During training, I would like to be able to view this set in tensorboard but keep the *same* triad throughout training.

If one naively uses tf.summary.image for each of input/ground truth/prediction tensorflow changes the saved image/ground truth/prediction set with each epoch.

I.e. right now I have

```
 #image example save
        tf.summary.image("input", test_x, max_outputs=3)
        tf.summary.image("ground_truth", test_t, max_outputs=3)
        tf.summary.image("prediction_output",output, max_outputs=3)
```

which does save 3 images from each epoch, but because they change with each epoch its hard to keep track of progress.

This would be useful just to get a crude qualitative understanding of what the network is learning in the process of training.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick hack. I would suggest narrowing down the set of images you forward to the summary:

```
#image example save
        tf.summary.image("input", test_x[:3], max_outputs=3)
        tf.summary.image("ground_truth", test_t[:3], max_outputs=3)
        tf.summary.image("prediction_output",output[:3], max_outputs=3)
```

Comment: Clever -- This potentially could work really well for something like validation data where you typically run only one batch.  If you wanted to implement in training it might be a bit more complicated with multiple batches.  i.e. when "output" is a tensor filled up with the output from each batch you would have to keep track of where you were in the dataset.   I'm going to keep question open to see if anyone has another answer more integrated with TF api.

Comment: Yeah, in that case I am afraid you have to create a separate tensor from your input df `visualization_batch=unshsuffled_input[:batch_size]` and feed it into network manually at the end of each epoch. But maybe you will not have to regenerate the model with weight sharing for visualization only as long as your batch size is either flexible or same as in the training (just saying ;)